# canvas.drawbitmap not work sometimes

Tags: android, canvas, drawbitmap

I used `canvas.drawbitmap(bitmap,matrix,paint)` to draw the bitmap on canvas.
yes, it worked most of the time! But sometimes it did not work. There was nothing on canvas after I called the method `canvas.drawbitmap();`
So, what`s wrong?

1: I chose a picture from the album and got the Bitmap which named `bgBitmap`

2: Created a `CanvasView` which extends `View`. Then Create a empty bitmap on canvas that to paint something on it.

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);  
mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);   
}
```

3: draw the picture on the canvas.

```
mCanvas.drawBitmap(bgBitmap,matrix, bitmapPaint);
this.invalidate();
```

It worked on most of the time, but sometimes it did not work.

Comment: show your codes

Answer (score 0):

1:
 I chose a picture from the album and got the Bitmap which named bgBitmap;

2:
 Created a CanvasView which extends View.Then,Create a empty bitmap on canvas that to paint someting on it.

```
 mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
 mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);  
 mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);   
}
```

3:
 draw the picture on the canvas.

```
 mCanvas.drawBitmap(bgBitmap,matrix, bitmapPaint);
 this.invalidate();
```

it worked on most of the time,but sometimes it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem....at first "canvas.drawBitmap()" worked, but then it stopped working, depending on what bitmap I was trying to display.  I was working with photos.  I downscaled a 24Mb panorama photo to about 400K, but even that was too large. When I reduced the jpeg size even further, (downscaling the resolution - not reducing colour quality), it started working reliably.